# What's special about Prime95's torture testing?

Tags: cpu, prime95

Overclockers often use [Prime95's Torture Test](http://www.playtool.com/pages/prime95/prime95.html) to stress-test their CPUs, but what I don't understand is that why overclockers don't prefer other programs that stress CPU to 100%, for example, anyone can write a tight loop like `int i=0; while (true) { i = (i + 50*i*i + 127) % 10003; }`, and we can also use the Unix `yes` command, or Blender's Cycles rendering engine. What's special about Prime95's torture testing?

Note: I want an answer about the nature of the Prime95's computation. I know Prime95 raises CPU temperature faster than other programs, and also, Prime95 can cause [strange noise](http://www.overclock.net/t/1269103/general-concensus-on-mobo-noise-under-load) on some computers, and I can't find or write any other CPU-intensive program to cause that noise.

Comment: Utterly unscientific answer? Everyone uses it. It works in a reasonably consistent, well understood manner. ;p

Answer (score 1):

Prime95 is not "special" in any way.

Its popular because:
- Tests for miscalculations (without OS crash)
- Designed to stress several cores at once
- Can be run in background while doing other things
- Easy to use
- Free